# Using the return of a user defined function in an :execute statement

Tags: vimrc, functions, vim9, execute

I am trying to get the output of the following function to an `:execute` statement such as I have this in my `.vimrc`

```
def GetBufAbsPath(): string
    return substitute(expand("%:p"), '[^\/]\+$', '', '')
enddef

noremap <F5> :execute '!echo ' ..  GetBufAbsPath() <CR>
```

And upon pressing  I am getting

```
E117: Unknown function: GetBufAbsPath
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem :-| Could you share with us your version of Vim (`:version`)? Can you reproduce the problem with a very simple version of the `.vimrc` that you can share with us?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `CTRL-R=` directly here. Also, it seems like you're trying to emulate `expand('%:p:h')`

```
nnoremap <silent> <F5> :<c-u>!echo <c-r>=expand('%:p:h')<cr><cr>
```

(I'm also not sure why you try to execute `:!echo` instead of `:echo`. Let's suppose this is for having a *Minimal Working Example*)